# How to save date and time in an orderly format Firebase & Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a social app and I want to save the date and time of a post when someone uploads it. I want it to be saved for example as `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`. Currently this is how it looks

[image: Current date and time stamp]

So this is the code that I have in a method.

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timestamp){
    try{
        Date netDate = (new Date(timestamp));
        SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        return sfd.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

I expect it to save the date and time that the post was uploaded in the format I want. But my problem is uploading it correctly in the Firebase DB. This is how I am uploading my current fields.

```
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("postid", postid);
hashMap.put("postimage", myUrl);
hashMap.put("description", description.getText().toString());
hashMap.put("publisher", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

I am trying to upload the timestamp like:

```
hashMap.put("date_time", getTimeDate() );
```

But when I hover over the parenthesis next to `getTimeDate()` it says `Expected 1 arguments but found 0`
so I'm guessing I have to use a string instead of the method name. Can someone help me on what to do ?

Comment: You have to pass one parameter since your is `getTimeDate(long timestamp)`. If you want to get current time better change `Date netDate = (new Date(timestamp));` to be `Date netDate = new Date();` and your function is only `getTimeDate()`

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA All I understood was change `Date netDate = (new Date(timestamp));` to `Date netDate = new Date();`

Comment: I don't understand what else you said

Comment: Then change your `public static String getTimeDate(long timestamp)` to be `public static String getTimeDate()`

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA thanks do you want to put that as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: You're welcome, I have posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get current time when someone upload the data, you can from `new Date()` and change your method without having a parameter argument

```
public static String getTimeDate() { // without parameter argument
    try{
        Date netDate = new Date(); // current time from here
        SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        return sfd.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```